# Running gazebo on Docker affects simulation speed, meshes, and world objects

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have the following setup:

- gazebo gets launched in docker with `gui:=false` via a `roslaunch` command (which eventually calls `gazebo_ros empty_world.launch`)
- `gzlient` gets launched on my local machine. I connect it to the docker container by setting `GAZEBO_MASTER_IP=$(docker inspect --format  '{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.a3cnet.IPAddress }}' [container])` and `GAZEBO_MASTER_URI=$GAZEBO_MASTER_IP:11345` before running `gzclient`.

I am encountering the following three problems:

1. Even though `real_time_update_rate` is set to 0 in my `.world` file, the simulation seems to be running at realtime.
2. My robot shows up, but all other objects in the world are not displayed in the GUI. I have also tried running `roslaunch gazebo_ros rubble_world.launch` as well as several other `gazebo_ros` launch files and the walls and such still do not show up.
3. `gzclient` throws errors for the meshes in my robot model because it is looking for the absolute paths in my docker file. Specifically, all the meshes in my docker container are located at `/catkin/src/tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo/meshes`. Of course they are located elsewhere on my local machine. Is there a way to correct this?

I am running gazebo 7.7.0 locally and 7.6.0 on the docker. I am using ros kinetic.

Thank you for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16076/running-gazebo-on-docker-affects-simulation-speed,-meshes,-and-world-objects/) by [ethanabrooks](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3126/ethanabrooks/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-05-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I solved 1. and 2. by adding `verbose:=true` when launching `empty_world.launch`. This seems a bit hacky, but as I understand, when `command_args` remain blank in `empty_world.launch`, `gzserver` does not properly parse the arguments and tries to treat `ode` as the `world_file` argument. I discovered this because, when I hard-coded `--verbose` at the end of the call to `gzserver` in `empty_world.launch`:

`<node name="gazebo" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="$(arg script_type)" respawn="$(arg respawn_gazebo)" output="screen" args="$(arg command_arg1) $(arg command_arg2) $(arg command_arg3) -e $(arg physics) $(arg extra_gazebo_args) $(arg world_name)" --verbose />`

I got the following error: `Could not open file[ode]`. So there seems to be some problems with how those arguments are passed to `gzserver` in `empty_world.launch`.

Problem 3 remains open but it is identical to [this question](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15618/gzclient-tries-to-load-mesh-with-absolute-filename/?comment=16075#post-id-16075).

---

Originally posted by [ethanabrooks](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3126/ethanabrooks/) with karma: 3 on 2017-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0